# How to partition the L3 cache in linux?

Tags: caching, multicore

My intel i3 processor having L3 cache of size 3072kb i want to partition(divide) L3 cache based on the number of cores present which is 2 in intel i3 Clarkdale. If anyone have done something related to cache then please reply?

Comment: You really need to be more precise, what have you tried? And you should also pick better tags. I'm not sure what you mean with "partitionning the L3 data cache".

Comment: @Emilien. Neither do I, but Google defines "partition l3 cache" perfectly well.

Comment: If the question is related to the few research papers that google yields, then I don't know any Linux mechanism to do that. However if you need to benchmark a given application (with different layouts for the input dataset?) for cache miss/cache hit, you can use KCacheGrind (http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html)